# Sorting a list of <Object a> by the value of it's Map <Object b, Integer int> results in a crash for objects with different private fields

Tags: java, sorting

I have the following list of objects of type `Supplier`. Every object has a private Map `<Drug, Integer>` (every Drug has price and name) and I am sorting them successfuly by the Maps value. However, I get a crash when I try to sort the list, if there is `Drugs` with different price. I'm pretty sure that this is something really small that I am missing here, but I've hit the wall here.
Here is my `Supplier` class:

```
public class Supplier  {
    private String supplierName = "";
    private String representative = "";
    private String representativesPhoneNumber = "";

    private Map<Drug, Integer> listOfDrugs = new HashMap<Drug, Integer>();

    Supplier(String n, String rep, String repPhoneNum, String drugName, double drugPrice, int stock) {
        this.supplierName = n;
        this.representative = rep;
        this.representativesPhoneNumber = repPhoneNum;
        listOfDrugs.put(new Drug(drugName, drugPrice), stock);
    }

    public Map<Drug, Integer> getListOfDrugs() {
        return this.listOfDrugs;
    }

    public static Integer getKeyExtractor(Supplier supplier, Drug drug) {
        return Optional.ofNullable(Optional.ofNullable(supplier.getListOfDrugs())
                                   .orElseThrow(() -> new IllegalArgumentException("drugs is null")).get(drug))
                       .orElseThrow(() -> new IllegalArgumentException("the drug couldn't be found"));
    }

public int getDrugsStock(String drugsName) {
    for (Entry<Drug, Integer> entry : listOfDrugs.entrySet())
    {
        if(entry.getKey().getDrugsName().equalsIgnoreCase(drugsName)) {
            return listOfDrugs.get(entry.getKey());
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

}
```

It has a `Map` if objects `<Drug, Integer>`.
Here is my `Drug` class:

```
public class Drug {
    private String name = "";
    private double price = 0.0;

    Drug(String n, double p) {
        this.name = n;
        this.price = p;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;
        result = prime * result + ((name == null) ? 0 : name.hashCode());
        long temp;
        temp = Double.doubleToLongBits(price);
        result = prime * result + (int) (temp ^ (temp >>> 32));
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;
        Drug other = (Drug) obj;
        if (name == null) {
            if (other.name != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!name.equals(other.name))
            return false;
        if (Double.doubleToLongBits(price) != Double.doubleToLongBits(other.price))
            return false;
        return true;
    }
}
```

Most of the code is trimmed, for the sake of spam. :)

And my `Orders` class, where I actually do the sorting:

```
public class Orders {
    private Map <Drug, Integer> orderedDrugs = new HashMap <Drug, Integer>();
    private Vector<Supplier> suppliers = new Vector <Supplier>();   

        public List<Supplier> sort(Drug drug, List<Supplier> suppliers) {
    List<Supplier> bufferList = new ArrayList <Supplier>();
    for (Supplier s : suppliers) {
        if(s.getDrugsStock(drug.getDrugsName()) != 0) {
            bufferList.add(s);
        }
    }
    Collections.sort(bufferList, Comparator.comparing(s -> Supplier.getKeyExtractor(s, drug)));
    Collections.reverse(bufferList);
    return bufferList;
}
}
```

The code is trimmed again, only displaying the needed methods for the actual problem.

And here is a sample from my `main`:

```
            Drug drug = new Drug("product1", 27.6);
            for(Supplier s : orders.sort(drug, orders.getSupplierList())) {
                System.out.println(s);
            }
```

So here, if I have 2 `Suppliers` and they both have `Drugs` with name `product1`, but with different prices, I get the following crash:

```
xception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: the drug couldn't be found
    at myapp.Supplier.lambda$1(Supplier.java:72)
    at java.util.Optional.orElseThrow(Unknown Source)
    at myapp.Supplier.getKeyExtractor(Supplier.java:72)
    at myapp.Orders.lambda$0(Orders.java:97)
    at java.util.Comparator.lambda$comparing$77a9974f$1(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.TimSort.countRunAndMakeAscending(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.TimSort.sort(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Arrays.sort(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.ArrayList.sort(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Collections.sort(Unknown Source)
    at myapp.Orders.sort(Orders.java:97)
    at myapp.main.main(main.java:77)
```

I want to sort the list of `<Suppliers>` by the `Suppliers` Map value, for different `Drugs` prices.
Example:
`Supplier1 <new Drug(drug1, 7.66), 50>`
`Supplier2 <new Drug(drug1, 6.72), 30>`
`Supplier3 <new Drug(drug1, 8.94), 15>`
The Map's value is the quantity of the Drug and I want to sort all suppliers by it.
Thank you for the help in advance and I'm sorry for the long post!

Comment: Trick question, your code doesn't compile because there's no `getDrugsStock` method in `Supplier`.

Comment: I am terrible sorry, I missed to post that method in my post. Edited now. However, that is not the problem. :)

Comment: It still doesn't have one. However, that method is relevant to the problem.

Comment: @immibis, I added it now - I've put the wrong method in the first edit. I'm just really tired, searching for a solution to this problem and I'm doing stupid things. :/ So here is the method - the code compiles, the problem is when I sort it.

Answer (score 1):

During filling the bufferList in Orders.sort() you only check for the Drug.name and not for the price. In this case you get a supplier in the list to sort which not holds the Drug.

Comment: But I don't want to check for Price at all. Drug price is supposed to be different for every Drug, even if they all have the same Drug name, since there is different Suppliers that sale the Drug in different prices.

Comment: But in the sort operation you try to get an Integer value out of getKeyExtractor(s, d) which cannot found the drug on the given supplier. Because the prices on the suppliers are different the drugs have different hash and Equals values.

Comment: Ah... :( is there anyway to fix this?

Comment: I see two possibel solutions.

Comment: Remove the price from equals ans hash from drug and store the price in an extra map at the supplier.

Comment: Another solution is to remove the price for hash and equals but hold it in the Drug. Then you have to "ask" the supplier for a drug which has the information about the price. Then I would also suggest to change the map by using the name as the key.

Comment: Hmm, actually - if I remove just the hashCode and equals implementation for price it works! Now even if I enter a price that is not in the Map at all it sorts by the name! :) Thank you !!!

Answer (score 0):

You have more than one Drug with the same name.

Suppose supplier1 sells a Drug called "Tylenol" and supplier2 also sells a Drug called "Tylenol" but these are separate Drugs.

You then create a third Drug called "Tylenol", but when you call `supplier1.getDrugsStock("Tylenol")` it returns the first Drug and when you call `supplier2.getDrugsStock("Tylenol")` it returns the second Drug, so you add both of these suppliers to `bufferList`.

Then you call `supplier1.getDrugsStock().get(thirdDrug)` which returns `null` because supplier1 only stocks the first Drug.